# MySql how to order results after a number format?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I want to return the results ordered by the result of the tcv SUM in descending order. This works fine if I remove the FORMAT() function but when I add the FORMAT() function to the SUM it returns the results in order of the first digits rather than looking at the entire number.

So it would return 87,400.00 before 7,456,234.00 because 8 is after 7 which is obviously not the desired result.

```
SELECT
x.user as user, u.name, 
FORMAT(SUM(IF(x.stage IN ('Closed Won') AND x.close_date BETWEEN '2018-04-01 00:00:00' AND '2018-04-30', x.amount_base, 0)), 2) as tcv, 
FORMAT(SUM(IF(x.stage IN ('Closed Won') AND x.close_date BETWEEN '2018-04-01 00:00:00' AND '2018-04-30', x.mrr_base, 0)), 2) as mrr,
FROM table AS x 
LEFT JOIN users u ON x.owner = u.name WHERE x.resign_new = 'New' AND x.owner IN ("Name 1", "Name 2", "Name 3")  
GROUP BY x.owner   
ORDER BY tcv DESC
```

I need the format in place as the numbers need to be formatted with the comma separator for readability.

What am I doing wrong for MySQL to be returning me ORDER BY incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

The sum function returns a decimal or double depending on the data type of the column you are aggregating. Thus, to sort it properly you can remove the format clause in the order by. See below.

```
SELECT
x.user as user, u.name, 
FORMAT(SUM(IF(x.stage IN ('Closed Won') AND x.close_date BETWEEN '2018-04-01 00:00:00' AND '2018-04-30', x.amount_base, 0)), 2) as tcv, 
FORMAT(SUM(IF(x.stage IN ('Closed Won') AND x.close_date BETWEEN '2018-04-01 00:00:00' AND '2018-04-30', x.mrr_base, 0)), 2) as mrr,
FROM table AS x 
LEFT JOIN users u ON x.owner = u.name WHERE x.resign_new = 'New' AND x.owner IN ("Name 1", "Name 2", "Name 3")  
GROUP BY x.owner   
ORDER BY (SUM(IF(x.stage IN ('Closed Won') AND x.close_date BETWEEN '2018-04-01 00:00:00' AND '2018-04-30', x.amount_base, 0))) DESC
```